# Input/Output error while playing video

Tags: linux, hard-drive, video, linux-mint, hardware-failure

I am using Linux Mint 15. Nowadays I am getting Input/Output error while watching movies. Sometimes when I copy/paste, I get the same error. What should I do? I have a laptop so unable to check inside the machine. 
 If the hard disk is corrupt, how to take the backup as I am unable to copy/paste the data.

Edit-
  The VLC error message is -

```
File reading failed: VLC could not read the file (Input/output error)
```

The system logs are below

```
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411430] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct     0x7fffffff SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411434] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411438] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411444] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:d0:85:b1/00:00:15:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411444]          res 41/40:00:d0:85:b1/00:00:15:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411448] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.411450] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler ntfs-3g[2726]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler ntfs-3g[2726]: ntfs_attr_pread error reading '/Dexter.1x07.Circle.Of.Friends.HDTV.XviD-LOL.[tvu.org.ru].avi' at offset 229416960: 4096 <> -1: Input/output error
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430101] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430139] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430144] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430147] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430151] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430154] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430161] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430164]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430183]         15 b1 85 d0 
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430192] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430199] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430203] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430211] Read(10): 28 00 15 b1 85 d0 00 00 08 00
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430221] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 363955664
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430225] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 6553274
Sep 26 21:08:30 gambler kernel: [ 6038.430258] ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: What is the precise error?

Comment: File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).

I get this error most of the times. I can't find much detailed error logs.

Comment: From your error log: `Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed`. This means that it is a drive error and not a VLC error. YOu will get the same error when you try to copy the file, open when you try to read it in an editor, etc etc. The most likely cause is a bad sector on the disk. To check for that read the [SMART values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart) from the disk. Then look at [the postings tagged SMART](http://superuser.com/search?q=smart) here on [SU]. You will discover that the question which you wanted to ask has already been asked and answered.

Comment: As to the `If the hard disk is corrupt, how to take the backup as I am unable to copy/paste the data.` 1) Restore from backups. 2) In emergencies use ddrescue. (Same as smart, asked dozen times on [SU] and there are quite a few answer. So I am not going to add yet another answer. :)